# Wordpress Sphinx и транслитерация

Tags: wordpress, поиск, sphinx

Приветствую.
Установил плагин Sphinx Search for Wordpress (
https://www.ivinco.com/software/wordpress-sphinx-search/ )

Хотел бы узнать, как сделать так, чтобы поисковик Сфинкс искал с помощью транслитерации?

К примеру я пишу Paris и поиск происходит по запросу и Paris и Париж

Заранее благодарен!

Answer (score 0):

Так никак не получится сделать. Paris и Париж - это не транслитерация, а перевод.

Comment: Окей, а если имеется в виду Parizh - чтобы это стало Парижем?

Возможно неточно указал задачу

Comment: Надо видоизменить вопрос, точнее указав желаемые параметры. Если это транслитерация, то по какому стандарту - ГОСТ 7.79-2000, ГОСТ 16876-71, СЭВ 1362-78 и прочие.